# Get the timestamp of user's last login in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, authentication, timestamp

I am starting to auditi my jenkins users. How can I get the timestamp of user's last login in Jenkins?

Groovy script example here (https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/get-lastlogin-users.groovy) returns the last time user's granted authorities changed, not the timestamp of the last login.

EDIT: I am looking for a way to get a list of the users and the timestamp of the last sign in.

Comment: Actually I tested that with LDAP autentication, the property LastGrantedAuthoritiesProperty of the example gives the user first login, and no data if never logged in.

Answer (score 2):

My solution by now:

- Create a new log in Jenkins > Manage > System Log
- Entering the Logger: `org.acegisecurity.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider` (I am using LDAP authentication)
- Log level: `FINE`

[image]

It provides a list of all users loggins into the system with the timestamp. Just filter the list to get the last time each user logged in.

Comment: The packages have changed over time. Refer  https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/troubleshooting-guides/cannot-make-my-ldap-configuration-to-work

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these lines to `/etc/default/jenkins` above JENKINS_ARGS:

   ```
   # Enable access log
   JENKINS_ACCESSLOG="--accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access.log"
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/default/jenkins` and add  `$JENKINS_ACCESSLOG` to `JENKINS_ARGS`
3. Enable log rotation: edit `/etc/logrotate.d/jenkins` and change `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` to `/var/log/jenkins/*.log`

For more reference, visit: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Access+Logging

Comment: Actually this solution do not save the username that signs into the system, but records all the http requests to jenkins into the log file. Then it does not solves my necesity. Thanks.