# How to find the users who haven't logged in Jenkins from past 1 year by using Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have gone through the below links but those are Jenkins UI change. But my requirement is by using Groovy script I need to find the users who haven't logged in Jenkins past 1 year.

[Get the timestamp of user's last login in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371905/get-the-timestamp-of-users-last-login-in-jenkins)
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Access+Logging

Comment: Which authentication type are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Jenkins own user database with Role-Based Strategy. Please help me how to find the users who haven't logged in user. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try out the following script: https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/get-lastlogin-users.groovy

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. Yes I tried that script already but that script is, Timestamp is not the date of the last login. It is the last time granted authorities changed, e.g., user group. Can you please suggest me on this. My requirement is to find the users who are not logged in past few days. Kindly help/suggestion me on this @Noam Helmer.

Comment: Then you can create a dedicated access log for the login audit. See [The following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371905/get-the-timestamp-of-users-last-login-in-jenkins)

Comment: Hi Noam Helmer
I have issue on Jenkins master and slave communication can you please suggest on this. I have Jenkins master on Linux and Jenkins slave is created on Windows10 and both are connected through .bat file configuration, Slave is going offline with below error:- connection was broken : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at.org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154) please suggest on this.